# Visual Studio Code's debug console doesn't run basic commands like LLDB?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, lldb

I'm trying to learn to debug using VS Code. I created a launch configuration in `launch.json`, for attaching to my process (a C++ program). I'm on macOS, so it uses LLDB. It attaches, and I can stop in a breakpoint and step through code. But nothing else is working well.

I'll focus my question here on the "Debug Console". I thought I'd be able to use LLDB commands, but it doesn't seem like it.

If I type `-exec bt` in the Debug Console panel, it responds with an error (below). Other simple LLDB commands don't work.

```
-exec bt
error: invalid target, create a target using the 'target create' command
-exec info registers
error: 'info' is not a valid command.
-exec p this
error: expression failed to parse:
error: <user expression 13>:1:1: invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
this
^
```

I'm stopped in a member function, so `p this` should work.

Is this "Debug Console" not connected to the current LLDB session? Should these commands be working?

In my `launch.json`:

```json
"configurations": [
   {
      "name": "(lldb) Attach to my_program",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/macos/my_program",
      "MIMode": "lldb"
   },
   ...
```

I tried another kind of debug configuration, where I launch it directly rather than attach (which I need in this case). In this case (launch instead of attach) I can run commands like `-exec bt`, and `-exec p this`. So something is different about attaching to a process.

VSCode: 1.79.2
macOS: 13.4
Extension CodeLLDB: 1.9.2
LLDB: from Apple Xcode 14: lldb-1403.0.17.64

Comment: please add version numbers for _all the things_

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. My main mistake was not changing my launch configuration to point to the new extension. The key: `"type": "cppdbg"` is wrong. It should be `"lldb"` instead, as [documented here](https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/blob/v1.9.2/MANUAL.md).

For example:

```json
{
    "name": "(lldb) Attach to myapp",
    "type": "lldb",
    "request": "attach",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/macos/myapp"
},
```

I also had to set the extension's `lldb.library` setting to point to my custom build of LLDB.

```
"lldb.library": "/Dev/llvm-project/build_phase3/lib/liblldb.dylib"
```